# How can I cache queries with Parse Server?

Tags: caching, parse-platform, parse-server

I have an iOS app that is using Parse Server, and I noticed that a lot of my queries are made on tables that are not changing often.

I would like to know if it's possible to cache (for instance every day) some of these requests using Parse Server in order to limit resources used and improve my capacity.

Thanks for your help.

Cyril

Answer (score 4):

For now we don't provide caching mechanisms, but you could implement it through a reverse proxy or another strategy in the front of your parse-server

For example, you can configure it with nginx, to cache the requests and serve them before you hit your parse-server installation

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/reverseproxycachingexample/